# How to automatically place cursor between braces on its own line using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I place an open brace in Visual Studio 2017 (C#) the cursor automatically goes to the next line to the left of the end brace. Like this (period as cursor):

```
if() {
.}
```

I'd like the cursor to automatically be on its own line like this (period as cursor):

```
if() {
    .
}
```

Does anybody know how to make the cursor automatically go where the period is in the second example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are at state 1 from your example use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This sends the line you are at one level down but keeps the cursor at current position. Effectively that will get you from state 1 in your example to state 2 in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile you are inside the parentheses of *if (.)* then use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I use Resharper hotkeys so you might have different combination find it out by going under **Environment -> Keyboard** and show commands containing **Edit.LineOpenBelow**.

This command is responsible for that action.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure because I am on VS 2013, but what you're looking for is probably in

Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> C# --> formatting --> New Lines

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically place the cursor inside the curly braces (i.e. without any shortcut), you can enable that from `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> (check) Automatically format braces when they are automatically completed`.

Of course, this is for C/C++. I don't use C# so I haven't tried for C#, but it should be similar, probably `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> (check) Automatically format block on }` (please correct me if I'm wrong).